# Azure Function fails to build when TFM is upgraded from netcoreapp3.0 to netcoreapp3.1

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, azure-functions-core-tools

We were trying to bump our dotnet version from a mix of .net 2.2 & .net core 3.0 to .net core 3.1 and we followed [Jeff Holan's Dev post](https://dev.to/azure/develop-azure-functions-using-net-core-3-0-gcm) to upgrade which is surmarised as below

*To change a project between ~2 and ~3 locally, update the .csproj file of the project and change:
AzureFunctionsVersion from v2 to v3
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package version to at least 3.0.1
Optionally, you can change to target netcoreapp3.1 if you want to target the latest .NET Core version*

But while debugging Azure function project locally in VS Code, it still failed with an error message suggesting that there were still config remnants pointing to 3.0. Anyone encountered this issue?

[[image: VS Code Azure Function Extension Error code]]

[[image: csproj + Task Host Run logs]]

Comment: Any reason for not upgrading to the latest version currently available `3.0.5`?

Comment: Oh no reason, it was just not germane to the error I was seeing during my debug process. If you have any experience with 3.0.5, I'm now curious to know

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that others can actually copy and use your proposed solution without having to re-type everything, and your answer can be properly indexed or read by screen readers."

Answer (score -1):

On doing a full project search, we found that VS Code itself stored [i.e. in its .vscode directory], namely in two files: settings.json and tasks.json. Some config key value pairs still pointed to .net core 3.0 [perhaps these were added during when we were debugging the project when these were the current framework]. So for the migration from 2.2/3.0 to 3.1 we need to to ensure the references to the older frameworks are removed

[image: setting.json]

[image: tasks.json]

1. We have to explicitly make the changes in tasks.json from netcoreapp3.0 to netcoreapp3.1

[image: Diff changes to tasks.json]

2. Ensure the deploy path in settings.json points to .net core 3.1
   [image: Diff changes in settings.json under .vscode]

PS: In settings.json, project runtime is bumped upto 3 if you have followed Jeff Hollans dev article, otherwise it will mostly point to  ~2

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that others can actually copy and use your proposed solution without having to re-type everything, and your answer can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.